# Add text in CSS chevron shape

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

A status bar made with a number of divs, Each has text status in the middle.
Generated the chevron shape with CSS, Shape made with joining two parallelograms. How I can add a text in the middle of each chevron.

[image]

```css
.chevron {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding: 12px;
  height:20px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top:30px;
}

.chevron:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #009999;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
}

.chevron:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #009999;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
}
```

```html
<div  class="chevron"> Text here</div>
<div  class="chevron"> Text here</div>
<div  class="chevron"> Text here</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give `z-index` to `:before` , `:after`

```css
.chevron {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding: 12px;
  height:20px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top:30px;
  text-align:center;
}

.chevron:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #009999;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
  z-index:-1;
}

.chevron:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #009999;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
   z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div  class="chevron"> Text here</div>
<div  class="chevron"> Text here</div>
<div  class="chevron"> Text here</div>
```

Comment: @ Anuresh May I ask why you add `clear:both` to `.chevron`, I'm not sure how it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You should consider using [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) in combination with a negative right margin instead of your `transform: skew()` approach. You would have way less code and the result is the same:

```css
.chevron {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin-right: -30px;
  background: #009999;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 0, 100% 50%, 80% 100%, 0 100%, 20% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 0, 100% 50%, 80% 100%, 0 100%, 20% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="chevron">Text here</div>
<div class="chevron">Text here</div>
<div class="chevron">Text here</div>
```

Comment: Will polygon method take any number of pairs as an argument?

Comment: Yes, every pair represents a point of the shape outline. The first and the last point will be automatically connected.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `z-index:-1` to the `.chevron:before` and `.chevron:after`:

```css
.chevron {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding: 12px;
  height:20px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top:30px;
  text-align:center;
}
.chevron:before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(60deg, 0deg);
}
.chevron:after {
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-60deg, 0deg);
}
.chevron:after, .chevron:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  z-index:-1;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #009999;
}
```

```html
<div class="chevron"> Text here</div>
<div class="chevron"> Text here</div>
<div class="chevron"> Text here</div>
```

Comment: z-index solved the issue. Thanks for the code refactor idea